# Element has height of zero in directive postLink method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to set the height of a DOM element based upon another DOM element, but the element has a height of zero during the postLink callback for the directive. It appears that the postLink callback is called before the directive HTML is added to the DOM.

I've tried to find an answer to get this to work, but so far no luck. I found a few answers referring to something called `$timeout`, but AngularJS manual says that is an alias for `setTimeOut`. Using a timeout callback just seems very wrong.

Another thing I read was to use a $watcher to observe changes in the DOM, but that too seems wrong to me.

```
cgTag.Navigate.NavigateDir = function()
           {
               return {
                   link: function(scope, $el, attrs)
                   {
                        var $navBg = $el.find('.cgNavBg');
                        var $sections = $el.find('.cgSections');
                        $navBg.css('height', $sections.outerHeight() + 'px');
                   },
                   template: cgTag.Common.templates.get('Layout.Menu')
               };
           };

cgTag.App.directive('cgNavigateDir',cgTag.Navigate.NavigateDir);
```

All I want to do is run code to setup my HTML after the template has been rendered.

I'm new to AngularJS but this seems straightly unintuitive.

Answer (score 0):

So `.cgSections` contains child elements that are created using `ng-repeat` on a scope variable collection. So I ended up using `$scope.$watchCollection` to set the height of the CSS.

This appears to have solved the problem, but I'm a little unsure as to why.

```
cgTag.Navigate.NavigateDir = function()
           {
               return {
                   link: function($scope, $el, attrs)
                   {
                       $scope.$watchCollection('sections',function()
                       {
                           var $navBg = $el.find('.cgNavBg');
                           var $sections = $el.find('.cgSections');
                           $navBg.css('height', $sections.outerHeight() + 'px');
                       });
                   },
                   template: cgTag.Common.templates.get('Layout.Menu')
               };
           };

cgTag.App.directive('cgNavigateDir',cgTag.Navigate.NavigateDir);
```

So AngularJS has this digest cycle that it performs when ever something in the scope changes. There is no *post digest* method in AngularJS. So you can only add watchers to be executed when things change. When a directive is first created it appears that the scope will be digested after postLink is called.

In my above fix. It makes better sense because if the collection changes in size the DOM element needs to be updated anyway.